# Get Table column names from xml using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have got `xml` from web service in below format

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <TelecallerName>AutoTelecaller_new</TelecallerName>
    <BASE>Aug 2015</BASE>
    <Location_x0020_Calling>0</Location_x0020_Calling>
    <NE>0</NE>
    <Sales_x0020_Open>0</Sales_x0020_Open>
    <TeleCaller_x0020_Follow_x0020_Up>1</TeleCaller_x0020_Follow_x0020_Up>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <TelecallerName>jiteshkumar</TelecallerName>
    <BASE>Aug 2015</BASE>
    <Location_x0020_Calling>1</Location_x0020_Calling>
    <NE>1</NE>
    <Sales_x0020_Open>1</Sales_x0020_Open>
    <TeleCaller_x0020_Follow_x0020_Up>29</TeleCaller_x0020_Follow_x0020_Up>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Here I want to get column Names like `TelecallerName`, `Base` etc. In short I want to find children of first `Table` node. How can I get it?

I have tried (suggested by charlietfl)

```
var x = $.parseXML(xml);
$(x).find('Table').each( function() {
console.log($(this).text());
});
```

But console gives

`AutoTelecaller_new    Aug 2015    0    0    0    1   (index):28
    jiteshkumar    Aug 2015   1    1    1   29`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u98077xL/)

Comment: Define "But not working." What if anything do you get in the console?

Comment: @jonmrich updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`children()` is a function but when you do `console.log($(selector).children)` without invoking the children function using `()` what you are seeing is the actual function itself, not what that function returns

Change:

```
console.log( $(x).find('Table').children );
```

To:

```
console.log( $(x).find('Table').children() );
```

The following creates an array of the tag names in the first `<Table>`

```
var x = $.parseXML(xml);
var $firstTable= $(x).find('Table').eq(1);
var colNames =$firstTable.children().map(function(){
    return this.tagName;        
}).get();

console.log (colNames);
```

Comment: Its working a bit but not exactly what I need. Its giving output like 
`[telecallername, base, location_x0020_calling, ne, sales_x0020_open, telecaller_x0020_follow_x0020_up, telecallername, base, location_x0020_calling, ne, sales_x0020_open, telecaller_x0020_follow_x0020_up, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[2], context: document, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, selector: ""…]`

repeatation and case conversion

Comment: WHat you need to do is loop over each `'Table'` using `$(x).find('Table').each(...` and then look inside that instance at the nested children for that instance to do whatever you need

Comment: you need the text of the specific children, not of the whole `Table`

Comment: No, I want to get headers as mentioned.

Comment: headers? What headers I don't see that mentioned anywhere. `headers` to me is part of an http request

Comment: I mentioned Column Names. It should mean the same. Pardon me for my english

Comment: use `$(element)[0].tagName`

Comment: added a method to create array of the tag names

Answer (score 1):

```
var xml ='YOUR XML HERE';
var mynodes =[];
mynodes = $(xml).children()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u98077xL/3/

`mynodes` is now a JSON array of each node and its values. You can just iterate through this (using `each` for example) and get whatever nodes you want.

Comment: sir, it gives me values but I want to get headers.

Comment: So, you want "TelecallerName" (for example) and not the values?